# Why the reasoner inferred that this class is a sub class of this class

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

This is my first class `Ratings2016`, it is an equivalent class to: Ratings and the value of createdOn bigger than 2016.

```
<!-- http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Ratings2016 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Ratings2016">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#createdOn"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom>
                            <rdfs:Datatype>
                                <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"/>
                                <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                    <rdf:Description>
                                        <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2016-01-01T00:00:00</xsd:minInclusive>
                                    </rdf:Description>
                                </owl:withRestrictions>
                            </rdfs:Datatype>
                        </owl:someValuesFrom>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>
```

This is another class `Ratings2015` it is an equivalent to Ratings and createdOn bigger than 2015

```
 <!-- http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Ratings2015 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Ratings2015">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#createdOn"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom>
                            <rdfs:Datatype>
                                <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"/>
                                <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                    <rdf:Description>
                                        <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2015-01-01T00:00:00</xsd:minInclusive>
                                    </rdf:Description>
                                </owl:withRestrictions>
                            </rdfs:Datatype>
                        </owl:someValuesFrom>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>
```

when I run the reasoner, the reasoner says that Ratings2016 is sub class of Ratings 2015

[image]

that is not correct, why is that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `xsd:minInclusive` to specify the date of creation. But, according to XMLSchema, `xsdminInclusive` specifies just a lower bound for a possible value. So, since `Ratings2016` has a date of creation which is greater than the date of `Ratings2015`, it is *enclosed* in the values specified for the `Ratings2015` (which starts from the beginning of 2015 and do not terminate), and belongs to that class.

A way of solving this problem depends of course from your problem, but maybe it could be sufficient for instance to declare also `xsd:maxInclusive` values for your Ratings.

Comment: please could you help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914679/why-protege-doesnt-infer-a-data-property-in-this-case