# why protege doesn't infer a data property in this case

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I have a class `Rates1.0` that is a sub class of the class the has a value `1.0f` for the predicate `ratesBy` as the following:

```
<!-- http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates1.0 -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates1.0">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy"/>
            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1.0</owl:hasValue>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

the predicate `ratesBy` is both data property and functional as the following:

```
<!-- http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy -->

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

I define an instance of `Rates1.0` call it `r1`, I run the reasoner in protege, but the reasoner doesn't infer that r1 has a data property `ratesBy` at all, why please?

I said that all `Rates1.0` have a `ratesBy` with value `1.0f`, and the `ratesBy` is functional

#### Update

This is the definition of r1 instance

```
 <!-- http://www.MusicSemanticOntology.com/mso#r1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.MusicSemanticOntology.com/mso#r1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates1.0"/>
        <rs:about rdf:resource="http://music.org/musicontology/mo#5th_Symphony"/>
        <rs:createdOn rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2016-01-01T00:00:00</rs:createdOn>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

#### Update 2

Even if I said that Rates1.0 is a sub class of `(ratesBy value 1.0f) and (ratesBy exactly 1 float)` still not infered that r1 should have ratesBy

**Hint: i know the using equvlent instead of sub class will solve but i need to know why sub class doesn't work in this scenario**

Comment: I think you want the type of the :r1 individual to be rs:Rates, not rs:Rates1.0?

Comment: @scotthenninger no no i want it to be Rates1.0 so the reason can discover (infer) that it has a ratesBy prediate with value 1 of type float

Comment: Protégé might not show data type property inferences by default.  You may need to specifically enable showing them.

Comment: Eg, see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499126/ontology-property-definition-in-protégé-owl-swrl

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor first do you know how  can I show them? secondly, it does show some of the other inferences, third, i already explored the ontology to jena sparql end point, and there is no the desired tribbles. Honestly this one is driving me crazy, why no inference, it is logical correct. even in the case of requivelent class not working,

Comment: Did you look at the question that I linked to?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i just finished looking, you've mentioned to configure the reaonser to show the data individuals, i did that (it was off) i restarted everything but still nothing :X :X . but i noticed that there you were using peller (more or less) reasoner, while in my protege, i have just one named `HermiT`, is that a problem please?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor funny story, i installed the latest version of protege, and installed the plugin for plellet and when i run it, i got error "patition null pointer exception" :) :) . let's stick to `HermiT`,

Comment: I'd suggest to get help for a particular tool and it's configuration on the Protege mailing list. I know that some inferences are shown while others are not, and this has been asked several times on the list, so maybe you'll get better help there. By the way, the reasoner is called Pellet and please use the term triples instead of tribbles :D

Comment: @aksw but also see [this resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Tribble) for RDF tribbles.